# Matching nth occurrence number in a string that contain hex number

Tags: regex, perl, hex

I have string that contain both word, hex and digit I want to match the number in the string but when the hex contain digit it will mesh out with my digit.

```
my $string = " aabb is = 35"; #where aabb is hex number  
my $string1 = " abc0 is = 75" ; #where abc0 is hex number
my (@val1) = $string =~ /(\d+)/g;
print "$val1[0]\n";
@val1 = $string1 =~ /(\d+)/g;
print " $val1[1]\n";
```

The above scripts can get the number after `=` that I want but I need to hard code `$val[0]` `$val1[1]` to get the number. Anyway I able to match the digit by ignore the hex number in case i am not sure which number will reach the number I want? So I can just print `$val1` to get the number I want.

8/30 Update, Thanks for Toto point out

Will be the case that first hex number contain all digit `1234` and also the number I want to match will not necessary be a last word in string. The number I want will not necessary the second number but will be after `=`

Comment: What about `"1234 1234"` where the first is hexadecimal?

Comment: @Toto, yes they will be the case so i confuse how to separate it

Comment: Do you allways want the second number in the string?

Comment: @Toto, thanks for pointing out my problem , i has edited my question with the clarification.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the hex may contain only digits (`1234`) the two numbers can't be distinguished by format.

The shown strings allow to match positionally (end of string) or based on `=` preceding it

```
my ($num) = $string =~ /([0-9]+)$/;

my ($num) = $string =~ /=\s*([0-9]+)\b/;
```

or make use of some other "landmark" in your strings, if different from shown samples.

Given the clarification in the question's edit the second example above is suitable.

---

*Original post, before comments (edited)*

A number won't have letters (unless it involves exponents), so use a word boundary

```
my ($num) = $string =~ /\b([0-9]+)\b/;
```

for an (unsigned) integer.

To allow `+/-` and/or a floating point format

```
my ($num) = $string =~ /( [+-]? [0-9]+\.?[0-9]* )/x;
```

but note that this leaves out some formats used for numbers.  The `looks_like_number` from core [Scalar::Util](http://perldoc.perl.org/5.8.9/Scalar/Util.html) is more reliable, and one can first match more broadly and then filter the list with it.

You can use `\d` instead of `0-9` but this matches many extra characters unless it is used with `/a` modifier(s), available since 5.14. But note that the `/a` has a broader effect than restricting to ASCII only numbers (`\d`). See [perlre](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html) (search for `/a`).

Comment: thanks for the answer, then i think i need to match by `=`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `(\d+$)` to match numbers only if they are at the end of string.

Answer (score 0):

How about?

This is matching the second number that exists in the string:

```
while(<DATA>) {
    my ($dec) = $_ =~ /.+\b(\d+)\b/a;
    say $dec;
}

__END__
hex abc123 dec 456 blah
hex 123123 dec 789456 blah
```

**Output:**

```
456
789456
```